# Microsoft Graph change notification using webhook how to get existing new messages after new subscription is created?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

We have a module called communication channel were user can create different communication channels, we have a type email_outlook as channel type whose job is to poll all incoming new emails from outlook. To make this work I have used microsoft change notification using webhook which notifies my application when new emails are received.

In communication channel we provide enable/disable functionality to the user, on disable I delete the existing subscription so don't send any new notification, but when user enables it we create new subscription, here comes the issue when new subscription is created we don't receive any notifications from MS side for existing emails that are in unread stage, it only sends new emails which are received after subscription creation.

My task is when subscription is created, MS sends all the unread emails (I know it provides notificationQueryOptions) to my service. How to solve this?

Below have added the current subscription payload

```
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://...../notifications",
  "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://...../notifications",
  "resource": "users/<client_email_address>/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2023-08-24T05:13:01.1216075Z",
  "clientState": "<random UUID>",
  "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
  "notificationQueryOptions":"$filter=isRead eq false"
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delta queries provided by microsoft on `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages`. This way you can sync mailbox from the state you had previously on your local database.

Comment: Okay, we now fetch all the missed emails (unread) but I will try your solution. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).